# Using Java lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

These are JavaScript:

```
function toCelsius(fahrenheit) {
    return (5/9) * (fahrenheit-32);
}
function area(radius)   
    {  
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;  
    };
```

How can I do the same thing in Java using the Lambda Expression? So far, what i understand is something like this:

```
(int fahrenheit) -> (5/9) * (fahrenheit-32);
```

But it shows error(illegal start type), i guess it's not correct.

Comment: Step 1: Open IDE.  Step 2: Write code.  Step 3: PROFIT!  (Read our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [edit] your question if you want a better answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has a generic interface `Function<T,R>` which you can use here to store these in.  The first type parameter is the type of the function's input and the second one is the type of the function's return value.

You could write your functions as

```
Function<Double,Double> toCelsius = fahrenheit -> 5 * ( fahrenheit - 32 ) / 9;
Function<Double,Double> findArea = radius -> radius * radius * Math.PI;
```

Then when you want to use them, you could write things like

```
double freezing = toCelsius.apply(32);
double pizzaSize = findArea.apply(11);
```

As a side note, don't write `5 / 9` in Java - this is an expression of type `int`, and its value is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `UnaryOperator<Double>` and `lambda` you can do like this :

```
UnaryOperator<Double> toCelsius = f -> (5 / 9.0) * (f - 32);
UnaryOperator<Double> area = r -> Math.PI * r * r;

System.out.println(toCelsius.apply(50.0));  // 10.0
System.out.println(area.apply(10.0));       // 314.159265...
```

---

`UnaryOperator<Double>` is same as `Function<Double, Double>`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [**`DoubleUnaryOperator`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleUnaryOperator.html) functional interface to perform the task at hand and also has the benefit of *not* boxing primitive types to their corresponding wrapper type or vice versa when performing the computation.

example:

```
DoubleUnaryOperator toCelsius = f -> 5 * (f - 32) / 9;
DoubleUnaryOperator findArea = r -> r * r * Math.PI;
```

to retrieve the result:

```
double celcius = toCelsius.applyAsDouble(40);
double area = findArea.applyAsDouble(24);
```